# Can I optimize a request containg WHERE Value <> 2 with an index

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Here is my request:

`SELECT TOP 10 * FROM BigTable WHERE Value <> 2;`

BigTable is a bit particular, as the `Value` column contains the same value for each row: `2`. In real cases, there might be a few rows which have a different value, but not many. I precisely need to find these rogue rows. However, I do not know which value (2 is just an example) at design time (but I do know at query time).

The request is slow (around 5 minutes) ; BigTable contains 10 million rows.

So I added an index on the `Value` column, which is of type smallint. 10 minutes later, the index was built, and I ran the request again. It is still very slow.

The issue can be reproduced here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ce0f/1

At this point, my guess is that SQL Server can not use an index for queries with `<>` operator, but I'm not sure why? For example, this other query takes only 2 seconds: `SELECT TOP 10 Value FROM BigTable GROUP BY Value` (and it returns a single row, with value `2` as expected).

I'm thinking about splitting into multiple queries: one to get the list of distinct values, and the others to fetch all rogue rows, such as `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM BigTable WHERE Value = x`, etc (all values that are not 2), but is there a better solution?

EDIT:

The idea for this query is to find rows that have NOT been updated after a process which updates most of the rows. Basically, I'm synchronizing with another data source. Each time I run this process, I increment the value, and it will update each row with the new value (as well as updated data). At the end of the process, I can then check which rows have the old value, and delete them. The process is a bit long, which is why I don't want to truncate the table first and insert after, as I need previous data to remain available during this process execution.

The index was created with this request (generated by Entity Framework Core, but I make my query tests by hand):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Value] ON [dbo].[BigTable]
(
    [Value] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

EDIT 2:

Here are the estimated query plan from SSMS (nothing top secret, but since I didn't ask if I could disclose what the project is about, I've blurred the database name ; also in these screenshots the table and column name are the real ones)

Query plan for `Value <> 2`
[image]

You can see that it doesn't use `IX_Establishments_UpdateTag` at all (the index scan is on the primary key). Execution time: 5min 18s (in this run, I had a single row whose `Value/UpdateTag` is not 2)

Query plan for `Value < 2`
[image]

Here the `IX_Establishments_UpdateTag` index is used. Execution time is less than 1 second (SSMS reports 0s).

Comment: The optimizer decides to use sequential scan when the selectivity is higher than 20%. I guess that is your case, therefore, the index is no help. However, why you are selecting so much data in the first place?

Comment: I'm not selecting a lot of data, in my current tests the query returns zero result, and this is what I expect. I just need a fast way to check there is no result, or if there are a few, I need to get them.

Comment: DId you try `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM BigTable WHERE Value NOT IN (2)`?

Comment: @StanislavL this is slow as well. Apparently, anything more complicated than `Value=1` (for example) is very slow.

Comment: There's no reason it shouldn't be using your index. What is the exact definition of it?

Comment: @rakwaht very slow as well. Beside, I was wrong in my question, `WHERE Value IN (0,1,3)` is slow as well (I've edited). But `WHERE Value IN (1)` and `WHERE Value IN (3)` are very fast. All these queries return no result (and this is what I expect)

Comment: @DavidG I've added the index definition in the question

Comment: Did you also tried to use the `!=` operator to see if there is any difference? BTW there shouldn't but could be an interesting experiment

Comment: What is the distribution of numbers in that Value field?

Comment: @Joe Phillips all the numbers are 2 in my current tests, which is why the query for `Value <> 2` returns no result. The problem is that it takes multiple minutes. I've also tested with `Value != 2` and get similar (slow) timing.

Comment: @youen Take out the top 10 and see what happens. Probably no difference but now I'm curious. This has got to be a simple statistics issue

Comment: @JoePhillips Still very slow without the `TOP 10` :-/ I'll take a look at the query plan and see if I can understand the statistics info. At this point I believe it is more or less a bug of SQL Server that should use the index, but thinks it's better not to, while in this case it would actually be 100 times faster.

Comment: I've added the query plans (estimated, but it matches the actual one)

Comment: Interesting. Can you reproduce using http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: @JoePhillips Sure enough: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ce0f/1 Apparently you need enough rows or even `< 2` won't use the index. With 10000 rows it works. But `<> 2` seems to always ignore the index.

Answer (score 1):

SQL can use indexes for `<>` queries. “Can” does not mean that it will, it only means that the optimizer will consider them.

SQL generally has problems using when `OR` is present—these usually (perhaps invariably?) result in full table scans. `Value IN (1,2,3)` has to be “translated” to “Value = 1 OR Value = 2 OR Value = 3`.

`Value < 2 OR Value > 2` looks obvious to you and me, but the optimizer is probably not smart enough to realize this is equivalent to `Value <> 2`... so it leaves it as an `OR`, and chugs along with a table scan.

As to why `Value <> 2` doesn’t run quickly, it’d depend on your data. Making some guesses and without going into necessary detail here:

- You have a lot of data (10 million rows, ok, but how many bytes per row? ...leads to discussion of Pages and Extents.)
- You say very few are <> 2 (or whatever your target value is)
- The query optimizer uses index statistics to determine whether or not to use a given index
- Statistics are built by sampling the data. If the data is that scarce, it might be that no non-2 values were sampled when the statistics were built, so the optimizer thinks all value are 2 and flags the index as largely useless.

(Statistics info can be looked at by running

```
dbcc show_statistics (<TableName>, <IndexName>)
```

*Understanding* statistics, however, is another thing entirely. If you want to go this far, check for relevant articles and discussions on the web.)

The above is a lot of “why”. Without diving into the data, analyzing the statistics, and guff like that, I don’t have a ready fix. As a though experiment, what if we turn your `< OR >` query into and `AND` query? Try

```
where not (Value >= 2 and Value <= 2)
```

Looks silly and may not work, but worth a try just to see what happens.

Comment: As an additional hint about the table size, displaying the properties in SSMS shows in the Storage tab (translated from french may not match exactly english SSMS terms): index size 2.4GB, data size 3.6GB. I have several indexes, one of which is on a computed column.

Comment: When I try the dbcc command, I get an error message (here is an approximate translation in english: "unable to localize IX_Establishments_UpdateTag statistics in the system catalog"). Unfotunately I won't have more time to dedicate to this issue since I already have a workaround that works well. Thanks for the explanations though, at least I know the index *should* work for `<>` operator.

Comment: "Unable to localize..." Now that sounds like an interesting problem!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a simple solution that seems to work fast :

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM BigTable WHERE Value < 2
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM BigTable WHERE Value > 2
```

Note however that in my tests, this query is slow:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM BigTable WHERE Value < 2 OR Value > 2
```

So I need to execute two distinct queries and concatenate the results afterwards. I don't know if there is a logical explanation to that.

Comment: This seems really weird to me, I would love to get to the bottom of it but without the db is going to be tough

Comment: I have a feeling your server simply doesn't have good statistics. Try calculating them and see what happens. Also, before doing that, try looking at the query plan to see why it's ignoring your index

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can use index for `<>` queries.

a simple query like below

```
select top 100 empid,custid 
 from orderstest where orderid<>230
```

with below index

```
create index nci on orderstest
(orderid)
include(custid,empid)
```

makes sql server use predicate in below format

> [1] Seek Keys[1]: End: [PerformanceV3].[dbo].[orderstest].**orderid < Scalar Operator((230))**,
>    [2] Seek Keys[1]:  Start: [PerformanceV3].[dbo].[orderstest].**orderid > Scalar Operator((230))**

and also estimates are also good regarding number of rows actually read to retrieve rows

> RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="100" ActualRowsRead="100"

so my guess on why your query might be running slow can be

1. you are reading all rows in a table  and if your index doesn't have all columns ,at a point entire table will be scanned

2.Also i believe network might  be a  bottle neck depending on how you are presenting all rows

for example,

below query which returns all rows and presents on SSMS

```
select empid,custid 
 from orderstest where orderid<>230
```

took 4 secs, but when executed with `discard results set after execution` it returns instantly

some other causes might be locking,blocking as well.. you can turn on actual execution plan and look out for wait stats in show plan xml..for my query below are wait stats

```
 <WaitStats>
              <Wait WaitType="SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD" WaitTimeMs="1" WaitCount="3" />
              <Wait WaitType="ASYNC_NETWORK_IO" WaitTimeMs="4942" WaitCount="4389" />
            </WaitStats>
```

Comment: Can't be a network bottleneck in my case since the query returns no result (all rows have Value = 2, but I'm querying those who are != 2, so no result...) I'll take a look at the query plan, I'm not used to SQL Server tools but that's a good occasion to expand my knowledge... that'll be tomorrow though